# How to order a List(of List(of string)

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting

I have a list(of list(of string)) in vb.net which is a list that contains lists that have 5 string list items in them.

I want to sort the lists by the second item in the contained lists but I don't know what parameter is needed in the .sort method. What do I need to put in as a parameter. I read something about writing a comparer function and putting that in the brackets but I don't understand how that works.

```
dim multiList as list(of list(of string))

multiList.sort(compare second item in lists)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to sort a list of something on the basis of a non-default criteria is to write a function which, given any pair of items, will return a positive integer if the first is greater than the second, a negative integer if the second item is greater than the first, or zero if neither condition applies (meaning the items have equal rank--not necessarily that they are "equal").  For example, if you're absolutely positive every inner list in your list of lists will have a non-null string as its second item:

```
    Shared Function CompareLists(L1 As List(Of String), L2 As List(Of String)) As Integer
        Return L1(1).CompareTo(L2(1))
    End Function
```

Then when you want to perform the sort:

```
    Array.Sort(myArray, AddressOf CompareLists)
```

If some lists might not have valid inner lists, you'll have to add code to handle all possible cases.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll be using a lambda expression like I saw in the other answer but your answer helped me to understand what was going on so you get the correct answer tick :)

Comment: @Aeropher: I understand lambda expressions, but I don't like the way they implicitly glom local variables into closures.  Slight changes to code can thus have major performance implementations.  BTW, I should have made the function above `Shared`, so as to avoid generating an extra delegate every time the `Sort` function is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a lambda expression to the Sort method:

```
multilist.Sort(Function(x, y) x(1).CompareTo(y(1)))
```

That will sort the list by the second element of each contained list.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'll be using but I didnt get enough details on how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Im not fully understanding what you are trying to do but have you look at sorted lists?

```
Dim list As New SortedList(Of Integer, String)
```

It works by sorting by the Key (the integer in this case), as i said im not sure quite what your asking but perhaps you can use this to resolve your problem.

Comment: I want to be able to sort by any value in the list rather than a key value. I chose an answer above that might show you what I meant :)